# How to make a bootable backup of Ubuntu

Tags: backup

I installed some software and set up some hardware on Ubuntu.

Now I would like to have a backup of it on a bootable CD to restore the system whenever I want.

What do I do?

Comment: I would recommend doing normal backups so you don't need to reinstall :P

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) At a minimum, could you provide the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else needs help. This software does the job and more 'systemback'

http://sourceforge.net/projects/systemback/

You dont need to install remastersys or pay for Black Lab Image creator. It's a very well design application and works great on 14.04

To install, open the terminal and do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback
```

then in case you plan to upgrade your system some day, just remove the ppa :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:nemh/systemback
```